# Fixing a -Werror=unused-but-set-variable

Tags: c++, compilation

This might be a silly question but I can't solve this without adding a print statement.

Here is my code

```
        double best_mother_index = 0;
        double best_mother_energy = -9999;
        double best_mother_plane = -99;

        for(size_t p=0; p< marks_mother_vector.size(); p++)
        {
           art::Ptr<simb::MCParticle> mother = marks_mother_vector[p];
           std::vector<double> mother_energy_recod = marks_mother_energy_fraction_map[mother];

           if( mother_energy_recod[0] > best_mother_energy){
                best_mother_index = p;
                best_mother_energy = mother_energy_recod[0];
                best_mother_plane = 0;
           }
           if (mother_energy_recod[1] > best_mother_energy){
                best_mother_index = p;
                best_mother_energy = mother_energy_recod[1];
                best_mother_plane = 1;
           }
           if( mother_energy_recod[2] > best_mother_energy){
                best_mother_index = p;
                best_mother_energy = mother_energy_recod[2];
                best_mother_plane = 2;
           }
        }

i get the following error message when compiling

:9: error: variable ‘best_mother_plane’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
  double best_mother_plane = -99;
```

why is that the only variable with a problem?
How can I solve this?

Comment: You're not using the variable at all. Why do you need the variable if you're not using it? The solution is to not have the variable if you're not going to use it.

Comment: If you are planning to use the `best_mother_plane` variable later in development  you can disable this warning temporally to just check that your program is otherwise compileable: `-Wno-unused-but-set-variable`

Answer (score 3):

> why is that the only variable with a problem?

Because that is the only variable that is set but unused.

> How can I solve this?

Either:

- Use the value of the variable for something. Think about how you want the value to affect the behaviour of the program.
- Or if you have no intention of using the variable, then remove it entirely.
- Technically you could declare the variable with [[maybe_unused]], but one of the above options would probably be better in this simple case. It's mostly useful when using macros to control conditional compilation (for porting to different systems).
- You could avoid telling the compiler to fail compilation when it notices such unused variable. One of the options mentioned above would be better, because such variable often indicates a mistake which makes this warning valuable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set the value of the variable but never read it in any way - it's basically useless. If you have plans on implementing usage of the variable then go ahead, otherwise do what the warning tells you and take the thing out: it's wasting memory and performance.

Comment: `it's wasting memory and performance.` Probably not as long as optimisation is enabled. If compiler is smart enough to tell you that the value is not used, then it should be smart enough to not bother wasting memory or performance for it.

Comment: @eerorika true, _if_ optimization is enabled